# Is is possible to view content of an .mdf file with NoSQL?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, mdf

I just want to know if it is possible to view content of tables in `.mdf` files with NoSQL for example mongodb? I don't want to change in `.mdf` file just view inside it.

Comment: No - `.mdf` files are SQL Server datafiles - you need SQL Server to do anything with them; their internal structures are not documented and thus not available for others to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say this, but you seem to completely lack any understanding about relational databases, NoSQL databases and the difference between them.

SQL Server and MongoDB are not only two completely different database products, but two completely different **kinds of databases** as well ([relational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) vs. [non-relational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)).

*Asking whether you can read SQL Server database files with MongoDB is like asking if you can edit AutoCAD files with Microsoft Excel (or the other way round).

Both are complex tools with their own file formats, but made by different vendors and for completely different purposes.*